# Angular Bootstrap - Circular dependency with modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have 3 components....

1) A component which has a button that opens Login Component (modal)

2) The Login component (this component has a button to open reset modal)

3) The Reset component (this component has a button to open login modal)

This is the user.module.ts (shared module)

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";
import {ResetComponent} from "./reset/reset.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent, ResetComponent],
    entryComponents: [LoginComponent, ResetComponent]
})
export class UserModule {
}
```

This is the login component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbActiveModal, NgbModal} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import {ResetComponent} from "../reset/reset.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    goToReset() {
        this.activeModal.close();
        this.modalService.open(ResetComponent, {size: 'lg'});
    }

}
```

This is the reset component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbActiveModal, NgbModal} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import {LoginComponent} from "../login/login.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reset',
    templateUrl: './reset.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./reset.component.scss']
})
export class ResetComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    goToLogin() {
        this.activeModal.close();
        this.modalService.open(LoginComponent, {size: 'lg'});
    }

}
```

It works as expected but I get this warning

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src/app/pages/user/login/login.component.ts -> src/app/pages/user/reset/reset.component.ts -> src/app/pages/user/login/login.component.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src/app/pages/user/reset/reset.component.ts -> src/app/pages/user/login/login.component.ts -> src/app/pages/user/reset/reset.component.ts
```

I think that it is normal this warning because in login.component I have to include reset.component and to reset.component I have to include login.component.... but I can't do something else. How can I fix this warning?

(My main goal is to change the component of the already opened modal

this.modalService.open(LoginComponent, {size: 'lg'});

I want from inside the LoginComponent, go to Reset Component)

Comment: You can do something else. For example, you could use a parent component that displays on or the other component, and deals with the navigation between the two.

Comment: This is the last solution.... but I can't image that I can't put a link inside login component to reset the password...

Comment: Emit an event from an output of the login component when clicking that link, and in the parent component, when the output emits, display the reset component rather than the login component. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: Can I simply ignore the warning? Is there any problem with memory leak?

Comment: Well, sure, you can.

Comment: You shouldnt let the Dialogs/Modals handling the opening and closing. Yes you are using a service, but you shouldnt do it inside them. Better subscribe to the dialogRef  from a parent and handle the modals depending from the received result, when the modals are closing/confirming/Saving and so on. Check this out https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3593#issuecomment-286397115